# None with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

As NFTs are becoming more popular, tracking their rarities is also part of it.  I am trying to retrieve the trait count from [this web page](https://rarity.tools/boredapeyachtclub/view/1) and when I inspect the page for the "Trait Count", which shows 5, I see the following:

```
<div class="flex-grow overflow-hidden">5</div>
```

So I use the following code:

```
import requests #fetches html page content
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #parses html page content

#Ensures we get English translated titles
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

#Get the contents of the page we're looking at by requesting the URL, timeout set to 5 mins
results = requests.get('https://rarity.tools/boredapeyachtclub/view/1', headers=headers, timeout = 720)

#parse html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")


#Grab the container that holds the company info
apes_div = soup.find('div', class_='flex-grow overflow-hidden')
print(apes_div)
```

And I get None instead of 5...

Edit

I have tried selenium with the following code and seem to get the same result:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")

driver.get('https://rarity.tools/boredapeyachtclub/view/1')

trait = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="flex-grow overflow-hidden"]')

print(trait)
```

Comment: it can be the most common problem: modern pages use JavaScript to add elements to page but `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried selenium with the same result, but have edited my post with the selenium code used.

Comment: Try changing trait to trait  in selenium method= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.flex-grow ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that, if you put a breakpoint on the `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` line, that it executes well before the page has completed loading.

This does what you were trying to do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="bin/geckodriver.exe")

try:
    driver.get('https://rarity.tools/boredapeyachtclub/view/1')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "p-0"))
    )

    traits = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="flex-grow overflow-hidden"]')

    print(traits[2].text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I just noticed an element with class `p-0` getting loaded as part of the needed payload, you might be able to find something cleaner. The `WebDriverWait` part causes the browser to wait until some condition is met, in this case an element appearing with the given class.

Also, you're looking for a `td`, but the data you expect is actually in a `div` - if you try to find a `div`, you find 8 of them, and the third one happens to be the one you're after.

The `try .. finally` is just there to clean up the browser once you're done.

(Note: I tried on Windows, so be sure to substitute your own code back to point at the correct driver)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much.  I'm curious though, where are you seeing the "p-0"?  When I right click on the white box and hit "inspect", and do a ctrl-f to search, p-0 doesn't come up (I only see the <div class="flex-grow overflow-hidden">5</div> and other classes above it, like "mb-1".  Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place though, as when I run your code, it shows "5" perfectly.  It makes me wonder where I might need t look to get the other traits, if not under inspect?Thanks again for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't remember exactly what element had the `p-0` class set, it looks it's in fact the monkey image, when I reload the page. Just search the rendered html content (after the scripts complete) for an element with that class. It's not on the box you're after, but that box loads at the same time as a bunch of other stuff - nothing stood out on the box that was easy to catch, so I looked for something else as a trigger.

Comment: You could however probably wait for an element to load that has the actual text of the field you're after - you'll have to look into the driver methods a bit more closely for that. The other traits are already in the result (`traits[0].text`, `traits[1].text`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I really appreciate your detailed response and am learning so much!